# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?

Tags: react-redux

trying to create an action in redux to call my API. I understand that actions must have a defined type so not sure why I am getting this error

Tried looking for similar posts but none of them provide the answer that I need

```
export const getTracks = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("/api/tracks/all")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
       type: GET_TRACKS,
       payload: res.data
  })
)
   .catch(err =>
     dispatch({
      type: GET_TRACKS,
      payload: null
  })
);
};
```

EDIT: MaieonBrix helped me realize that my import of 'GET_TRACKS' was missing from the file where my action types are located:

```
import { GET_ERRORS, GET_TRACKS } from "./types";
```

file types.js:

```
export const {GET_ERRORS} = 'GET_ERRORS';
export const {GET_TRACKS} = 'GET_TRACKS';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs when you are dispatching an action with an `undefined` type like so :

`dispatch({ type: variableThatMightBeUndefined })`

It means that your GET_TRACKS variable that holds your 'GET_TRACKS' string is undefined.

I will update my answer if you update your post with how you are importing your action (it may be related to that)

UPDATE :

The issue here is how you exported your types

```
// change this
export const { GET_TRACKS } = ...

// into this

export const GET_TRACKS = ...
```

Here is the documentation on named export : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Thanks @MaieonBrix, I realized that even though I did have the import statement , the action was missing from my 'types' file.

Comment: Actually , the error did not go away when I added the export from types.js... hmmm

Comment: remove the curly brackets around your variable name